# onchange event function showing not defined (Javascript-HTML-DOM)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I am using Javascript HTML DOM Events,When I run my code in the browser, it says statusHtmlFromObject is not defined. Can someone please tell what is the correct way of writing it inside html tag like I'm trying to do. I've attached the script.js file.

```
 File: Script.js
      function statusHtmlFromObject() {
      var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
      console.log('This is your selection', x);
    }
     var html = '';
     html +='<select id="mySelect" onchange="statusHtmlFromObject()">';
       html +='<option value="Order placed">Order placed';
       html +='<option value="Preparing">Preparing...';
       html +='<option value="Packaging">Packaging...';
       html +='<option value="Food is ready">Food is ready';
        html +='</select>';
      return html;
```

Comment: How do you render? How is the script file loaded?

Comment: I've added the script file in my html page and trying to get data inside a div, since I need to show some more data with this button later, it needs to be in the script file separately and can't add it directly on html page. I'm using html inside script file for the first time, getting really confused how to properly show it on html page. @NielsNet

Answer (score 0):

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
function statusHtmlFromObject() {
      var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
      console.log('This is your selection', x);
    }
     var html = '';
     html +='<select id="mySelect" onchange="statusHtmlFromObject()">';
       html +='<option value="Order placed">Order placed';
       html +='<option value="Preparing">Preparing...';
       html +='<option value="Packaging">Packaging...';
       html +='<option value="Food is ready">Food is ready';
        html +='</select>';
        container.innerHTML += html;
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<script src=""><script/>
```

This is working. You should append your html to a div tag or any other html element in general.

Comment: Actually I need to show this drop down on main html page inside a div, can't add it directly in html page using script tags, it needs to be in a separate script file that I've already included.

Comment: Then you should include the script(<script src=""></script>) after yor div tag in your main html page.

Answer (score 0):

Your statusHtmlFromObject function is declared inside another function.
It must be global accessible for onchange event.
This is reason of error.

You need to declare it outside or just define it globally:

```
var statusHtmlFromObject  = function (){
...
};
```

Comment: I think you're right. How to write it in select tag, for eg onchange=??

Comment: You don't need to change nothing. Onchange event in Your code triggers statusHtmlFromObject function. When You declare it in global scope then all will work fine.